# current code not extracting email headers for content-type

Tags: c#, outlook, add-in, outlook-addin, office-addins

I use code from this [link](http://www.lessanvaezi.com/email-headers-from-outlook-mailitem/) to get email headers from outlook.

But, it is not extracting email body(content-type) correctly. Everything works fine. If you want to compare, you can open gmail, see options for gmail and click 'show original' which shows headers correctly.

Providing code from above link:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

public static class MailItemExtensions
{
    private const string HeaderRegex =
        @"^(?<header_key>[-A-Za-z0-9]+)(?<seperator>:[ \t]*)" +
            "(?<header_value>([^\r\n]|\r\n[ \t]+)*)(?<terminator>\r\n)";
    private const string TransportMessageHeadersSchema =
        "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001E";

    public static string[] Headers(this MailItem mailItem, string name)
    {
        var headers = mailItem.HeaderLookup();
        if (headers.Contains(name))
            return headers[name].ToArray();
        return new string[0];
    }

    public static ILookup<string, string> HeaderLookup(this MailItem mailItem)
    {
        var headerString = mailItem.HeaderString();
        var headerMatches = Regex.Matches
            (headerString, HeaderRegex, RegexOptions.Multiline).Cast<Match>();
        return headerMatches.ToLookup(
            h => h.Groups["header_key"].Value,
            h => h.Groups["header_value"].Value);
    }

    public static string HeaderString(this MailItem mailItem)
    {
        return (string)mailItem.PropertyAccessor
            .GetProperty(TransportMessageHeadersSchema);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0

Received: by someip with HTTP; Wed, 3 Dec 2014 10:04:00 -0800 (PST)

Date: Wed, 3 Dec 2014 23:34:00 +0530

Delivered-To: test..@gmail.com

Message-ID: <somehashhere..g@mail.gmail.com>

Subject: <subject here>

From: test name <test @gmail.com>

To: test name <test @gmail.com>

Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=<somehash...>
```

Output from gmail(click 'show originl' in gmail message options):

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Received: by someiphere with HTTP; Wed, 3 Dec 2014 10:04:00 -0800 (PST)
Date: Wed, 3 Dec 2014 23:34:00 +0530
Delivered-To: test..@gmail.com
Message-ID: <somehash__@mail.gmail.com>
Subject: subjecthere
From: test name <test..@gmail.com>
To: test name <test..@gmail.com>
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=somehash

--somehash
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8

messagehere

--somehash
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

<div dir="ltr">messagehere</div>

--somehash--
```

Comment: As you step through your code, what exactly does not work? Is your regex right? Have you tested it with, for example, http://regexpad.com/#p-javascript? Does the header actually contain "header_key" or "seperator> (sic)?

Comment: mailitem.HeaderString() is returning whole data except the mail body. That is because mail body is shown in content-type(by gmail) and that it has several new lines, may be thats not handled in code. Thats not my code by the way, I saw somewhere online. 
I didnt test the code in regexpad yet, I will try

Comment: I added output from outlook aswell as gmail so you can compare.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

I know that is very old question, but I see it in top of google search so I want to share my finding for other guys

I have used bellowing code to get Content-Type in Outlook 2013/2016

```
if (Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Inspectors.Count > 0)
{
    Outlook.Inspector inspector = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector();
    if (inspector.CurrentItem is Outlook.MailItem)
    {
        Outlook.MailItem mail = (Outlook.MailItem)inspector.CurrentItem;
        string pidNameContentType = mail.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020386-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/content-type/0x0000001F");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS` property only returns the MIME headers of the main MIME part. The actual MIME data is not stored there. When a message is received by Outlook, the headers are parsed into various MAPI properties (e.g. "Subject" goes into the `PR_SUBJECT` MAPI property). Plain text body goes into `PR_BODY`, etc.

Take a look at an existing message with [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author) - click IMessage button and select the `PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS` property to see its contents.

**UPDATE**:
You can convert the message to the MIME format. It will not be the exact message that came in (the order of headers and MIME message parts might be different).  You can either

1. Use [IConverterSession](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff960231(v=office.15).aspx) MAPI interface (Extended MAPI, so C++ or Delphi only). You can play with that interface in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author) - click IConverterSession button on the OutlookSpy ribbon).
2. Construct the MIME message explicitly in your code.
3. Use [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) (I am also its author) and its [RDOMail](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOMail.htm).Save(..., olRfc822) method